# Sort by Last Name in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I am managing a static blog that has a large list of people's names. I need to sort the people alphabetically by their last name. How would one go about sorting by the last name where the name is a single string? For example:

```html
{% assign People = "John Smith, Foo Bar, Zee Mack Arlington" | split: "," %}

<!-- How do I sort People by last name -->
{% assign sortedPeople = People | sort_natural %}

{% for person in sortedPeople %}
  <p>{{ person }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

This gives me a list of people sorted alphabetically by the first name, but I need it to be sorted by the last name.

```
Foo Bar
Zee Mack Arlington
John Smith
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Liquid is a bit restrictive by design, but here's one way to do it:

```
{% assign sorted_names = "" | split: "" %}
{% assign names_prefixed_with_last = "" | split: "" %}

{% assign names = "John Smith, Foo Bar, Zee Mack Arlington" | split: "," %}

{% for name in names %}
  {% assign name_parts = name | split: " " %}
  {% assign last_name = name_parts | last %}
  {% assign name_prefixed_with_last = name | prepend: last_name %}
  {% assign names_prefixed_with_last = names_prefixed_with_last | push: name_prefixed_with_last %}
{% endfor %}

{% assign sorted_with_prefix = names_prefixed_with_last | sort %}

{% for name_with_prefix in sorted_with_prefix %}
  {% assign name_parts = name_with_prefix | split: " " %}
  {% assign last_name = name_parts | last %}
  {% assign name = name_with_prefix | replace_first: last_name %}
  {% assign sorted_names = sorted_names | push: name %}
{% endfor %}

{% for name in sorted_names %}
  <p>{{ name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

This outputs:

```
<p>Zee Mack Arlington</p>
<p>Foo Bar</p>
<p>John Smith</p>
```

First we create a couple of arrays with the split empty string trick, then fill an array with the names prefixed with the last name (e.g. "SmithJohn Smith"). We then sort that since it'll be sorting on last name, then fill an array with the values of the sorted, prefixed array with the prefix removed.

---

Although I don't have any other knowledge of the problem scope, the better way is probably sort it with something else and put it in a data file. You could also store them in an array as well instead of a huge unwieldy string.

Comment: Thanks for that solution. Don't think I would have ever got that right without your help! :)